# Can I create a function to clear variables in python ?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible in python to do something like this:

```
def number_clear(num):
    num = 0 
x = 10 
number_clear(x)
print x 
>>0
```

In C we could do that simply by pointers

Comment: This might help you convert from C expectations to Python expectations https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140747

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks, it sorted some confusions